# NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate always called with .update, never .move

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a FRC that I build like this:

```
let sort            = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath:     \Article.title,
                                       ascending:   true)
let fetchRequest    = NSFetchRequest<Article>(entityName: "Article")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors    = [sort]
let fetchResultController  = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest:         fetchRequest,
                                                        managedObjectContext: context,
                                                        sectionNameKeyPath:   nil,
                                                        cacheName:            nil)
```

And I set up a delegate for it.

Things are working fine, and I do receive updates of Articles lists, sorted by their title.

However, if I do:

```
anArticle.title  = "3 - My Modified Article"
```

I receive a delegate call to

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>,
                           didChange anObject: Any,
                           at indexPath: IndexPath?,
                           for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType,
                           newIndexPath: IndexPath?)
```

But `type` is equal to `.update`, when I should expect it to be `.move` as this re-orders the fetch request results.

How to declare that the `title` property is an ordering property of the FRC, so that I get `.move` in the delegate call ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why the delegate was not called with `.move`.

I was grouping modifications with some other insertion and deletions. So I was getting several calls to the method, in between calls to `controllerWillChangeContent` and `controllerDidChangeContent`. In such case, Core Data is smart enough to sometime send `.update` and not `.move` if not needed to declare the list will be re-ordered.

Separating the modifications and having the title update "on its own" led to receiving `.move` calls.